# How to join two paths and display to data list (Firebase Database and Ionic 2)

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

How to join 2 paths firebase database in ionic 2. i have 2 paths, '/Member/joinGroup' and '/Group'. i want to display information Group when i get group id on '/Member/joinGroup'. i will showing data in list data view.

Below shows the path column

```
Group
 -123
   -groupAdmin: test@gmail.com
   -groupName: test
   -groupPhoto: test.jpg
 -456
   -groupAdmin: test_456@gmail.com
   -groupName: test 456
   -groupPhoto: test1.jpg

Member
  -member1
   -memberName: james
   -memberPhoto: james.jpg
   -memberEmail: test@gmail.com
   -joinGroup
     -join1
       -groupId: 123
     -join2
       -groupId: 456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, here is the code

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    var personRef: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref().child(`Member/`+user.id+`/JoinGroup/`);
    var groupRef: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref().child(`Group/`);
        personRef.on('child_added', snap => {
        groupRef.child(snap.val().groupId).once('value', grup =>{
            //the result
            this.allmygroups.push(grup.val());
        });
    });
}
```

dont forget to declare variable allmygroups

```
public allmygroups= [];
```

and display the result on html ionic

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let grup of allmygroups">
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img [src]=grup.groupPhoto>
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{grup.groupName}}</h2>
</ion-item>
```